# Merge hash with properties arrays

Tags: javascript, hash

I have 2 hashes(objects) for ex.

```
hash1 = {myKey: ["string1"]}

hash2 = {myKey: ["string2"]}
```

I want to merge them together, so in the end i would get something like following -

```
{myKey: ["string1", "string2"] }
```

I tried `$.extend`, but that doesnt work for arrays as property

Comment: your keys do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a function for that.

```js
function add(o, v) {
    Object.keys(v).forEach(function (k) {
        o[k] = o[k] || [];
        v[k].forEach(function (a) {
            o[k].push(a);
        });
    });
}


var hash1 = { myKey: ["string1"] },
    hash2 = { myKey: ["string2"] };

add(hash1, hash2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(hash1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`Array.prototype.push.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Merging_two_arrays) to merge array

```js
var hash1 = {myKey: ["string1"]};
var hash2 = {myKey: ["string1"]};
Array.prototype.push.apply(hash1.myKey, hash2.myKey)
console.log(hash1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** check the case sensitivity of your keys.

You can do something like this:

```
hash1 = {myKey: ["string1"]}
hash2 = {myKey: ["string2"]}
var result = {};
for (var hash1Key in hash1) {
    if (hash1.hasOwnProperty(hash1Key)) {
       for (var hash2Key in hash2) {
          if (hash2.hasOwnProperty(hash2Key)) {
               if (hash1Key === hash2Key) {
                  result[hash1Key] = [hash1[hash1Key], hash2[hash2Key]]
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

See it live in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdezmLba/)